# Deleting and recreating folders in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I am using the program hazel to tidy my downloads folder every time a file is downloaded. I am now telling it to run a shell script, every week, to delete every folder in my downloads folder and then recreate it.

Is there an easier way to do this (deleting folders/recreating folders) by re-iterating through every folder in my Downloads folder and deleting its contents?

```
cd ~/Downloads;
rm -rf Archives;
rm -rf DMGs;
rm -rf Documents;
rm -rf Fonts;
rm -rf Mail\ Attachments;
rm -rf Mobile\ Provisioning;
rm -rf Music;
rm -rf Photoshop;
rm -rf Pictures;
rm -rf Videos;

mkdir Archives;
mkdir DMGs;
mkdir Documents;
mkdir Archives;
mkdir Fonts;
mkdir Mobile\ Provisioning;
mkdir Mail\ Attachments;
mkdir Music;
mkdir Photoshop;
mkdir Pictures;
mkdir Videos;
```

Comment: What about recursively deleting the "Downloads" folder and creating it back?

Comment: note: `;` is only needed if you have multiple commands in one line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
cd ~/Downloads && rm -rf */*
```

Or am I missing something?

Note: This will not delete hidden files/directories immediately under the top level.

Comment: Having deleted all of the folders, I want to re-create the folders with the same name

Comment: Trust us, it won't delete the outer folders, just their contents.

Comment: The above does not delete the folders - it deletes the contents of the folders.

Comment: This command is **unsafe**: if the `Downloads` folder is missing, it will delete everything in your home folder! When using `cd` like this, always either make the next action conditional (`cd ~/Downloads && rm -rf */*`) or set the exit-on-error flag (`set -e`) before `cd`ing.

Comment: @Kevin - good point. I've modified my answer

Answer (score 9):

If you want to delete files while leaving the complete folder structure intact, use

```
find . -type f -print -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

If you only need the top level folder structure intact, `rm -rf */*` as others have suggested is good

Comment: Find also includes the ability to only delete files that match certain criteria, so it's more flexible than rm.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simply, this will do it: `rm -rf */*`

Comment: Does that go through every-folder and delete its contents within the Downloads folder?

Comment: yepp. 9moretogo:)

Answer (score 0):

You could also run :

```
find ~/Downloads -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all files in that directory.

Replace `rm {} \;` with `ls -l {} \;` before running for real to check if everything is okay before deleting the files.